# Trouble formatting cells of table

Tags: c#, alignment, tablecell

I have a table with 1 row and 3 columns. But the columns are not aligned properly. It is displayed as follows:

[image]

```
Table _tbRequiredDocFormat = new Table();
TableRow row_requiredDocCount = new TableRow();                       
TableCell cellLabel = new TableCell();
TableCell cellFileInput = new TableCell();
TableCell cellBtn = new TableCell();  
//add label, RadAsyncUpload and Button to cells.//
//formatting as below::
this._tbRequiredDocFormat.Rows[requiredDocCount].Cells[0].Width = Unit.Percentage(30);
this._tbRequiredDocFormat.Rows[requiredDocCount].Cells[0].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;                       
this._tbRequiredDocFormat.Rows[requiredDocCount].Cells[0].VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Middle;
this._tbRequiredDocFormat.Rows[requiredDocCount].Cells[1].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
this._tbRequiredDocFormat.Rows[requiredDocCount].Cells[1].VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Middle;
this._tbRequiredDocFormat.Rows[requiredDocCount].Cells[2].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
this._tbRequiredDocFormat.Rows[requiredDocCount].Cells[2].VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Middle;
```

Despite all attempts, I cant bring the cells closer. I want the table in the center and the cells closer to each other so that it looks better. Please suggest a solution.

Comment: what kind of table are you asking about?  from what library, tool or namespace?

Comment: Post html of container of this table in which this table will be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your table is using 100% of the available width, so you may want to reduce that, ie: `_tbRequiredDocFormat.Width = 400`. Check your CSS isn't applying some styling that's causing this.  If that's not the solution can post the raw html?

To align your table add the style: `margin: 0px auto;` But as this is a control you're building up you'll have to create a CCS Class and call that, for example: `_tbRequiredDocFormat.CssClass = "CenterTable";`